# Unity: Реальный размер объекта

Tags: unity3d, ui, transform

Короче у меня есть куча UI объектов, и один из них вот этот:

[image]

Вот тут вы можете видеть что размер объекта 680 на 680:

[image]

Я хочу с помощью этого кода получить размеры объекта:

```
Debug.Log(PictureAndBackground.GetComponent< RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x);
Debug.Log(PictureAndBackground.GetComponent< RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y);
```

Но получаю 0 на 0:

[image]

Я понимаю что это связано с Anchor Presets. **Но что мне писать чтобы получить размеры объекта как на втором картинке, даже если у него Anchor Presets на stretch?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно поле `.rect` у вашего `RectTransform`. Класс `Rect` - как раз и представляет собой тот прямоугольник, который вы видите в редакторе у UI элементов.

И, да, `RectTransform` не обязательно получать через `GetComponent<T>()`, т.к. в классах наследующихся от `MonoBehaviour` всегда есть ссылка на `Transform` объекта, на котором они висят. Вы можете просто привести `.transform` к `RectTransform`)

```
var rectTrans = PictureAndBackground.transform as RectTransform;
if (rectTrans != null)
{
    print(rectTrans.rect.width);
    print(rectTrans.rect.height);
}
```